# Find origin of access violation in Mixed Code

Tags: c#, sharpdx, wic

I got the following code (using SharpDX.WIC / SharpDX.Direct3D11) which always throws an exception saying there was an access violation.

```
public static SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    // Allocate DataStream to receive the WIC image pixels

    int stride = PixelFormat.GetStride(bitmapSource.PixelFormat, bitmapSource.Size.Width);
    using (var buffer = new DataStream(bitmapSource.Size.Height * stride, true, true))
    {
        // Copy the content of the WIC to the buffer
        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
        return new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Width = bitmapSource.Size.Width,
            Height = bitmapSource.Size.Height,
            ArraySize = 1,
            BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Default,
            CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
            Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            MipLevels = 1,
            OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        }, new DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer , stride));
    }
}
```

The exception message is:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF894ECA25C (combase.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000008.

**EDIT**: Sometimes I get this exception instead:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8825283BD (WindowsCodecs.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

It occurs at this line:

```
bitmapSource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
```

I read somewhere that the `FormatConverter` requires all components, so disposing them before copying to the buffer results in invalid reads. Afterwards it worked, but then broke again without any meaningful reason. Now I always get this write access violation and I can't find the source.

I tried to figure out where it happens using the disassembly, but I have no clue where `0xC0000005` would be located. After all I don't get why this doesn't work. The code for this was from an older SharpDX sample code which has been referenced to a lot even on Stackoverflow. But it simply doesn't work. The underlying `FileStream` has *ReadWrite*-access and the `DataStream` is set to allow read and write operations.

Might this be an issue in the SharpDX.WIC codebase?

To keep this short and handy, [here](https://pastebin.com/sUkVznBX) is the full source in chronological call-order.

Comment: This is the way that unmanaged code fails.  All that you really know is that somebody bad happened with the underlying storage of that DataStream, given that it was a write that failed.   An address of 8 hints at a null pointer, 0xFF..FF is however far nastier and hints at a random pointer.  It often doesn't have anything to do with this specific code, memory corruption caused by earlier code is the common trigger.  That this is very hard to debug is the primary reason why managed code became popular.  Application Verifier might be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug AccessViolationException coming from native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245185/how-to-debug-accessviolationexception-coming-from-native-code)

Comment: @SharpShade did you ever resolve this? If so, could you please share the root cause?  For future readers: 0xC0000005 is the error code for Access Violation, not an address. Typically this error means that an address pointer was wrong or corrupted, and pointed to memory that was owned by somebody else. The first thing I'd look at in this case would be the bitmapsource that was passed into this method.

Comment: I actually don't remember. Been months since I last worked on that project. If I can give a solution, I'll update this thread.

Comment: @SharpShade, was this application built using x64 platform over a 64bit PC?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that some numbers got conflated with pointers.  Look at the memory addresses its trying to access:

- 0x0000000000000008
- 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

In integer form, these are 8 and -1, so it wouldn't surprise me if someone in the code, you're passing in numerical values where the API is expecting an IntPtr or such.  I don't have access to the particular library you're working with, but I'd take a very close look at what the argument types are and make sure you're not passing something it doesn't expect (or if there are any places you'd be passing a value of -1 or 8.)

Comment: The signature of this method is `BitmapSource.CopyPixels(int stride, DataPointer dataPointer)` - whereas the `DataPointer` is implicitly the buffer itself. It seems like that is some issue on SharpDX's side, so I guess I'll pass it onto their Issue page on Github for verification... After all I just used the sample code provided by them.